# Error in retrieving entity of HttpPost

Tags: android, entity, http-post, httprequest

Following is my code to post and then get response from the url...
Whenever i run the code I do not get the response in Bufferedreader...

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

    try{

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html");

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

     response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    }catch(Exception e){

    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

    }

    return null;

    }


protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

    Dialog.dismiss();
    HttpEntity httpEntity= response.getEntity();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "resp of :"+response.getEntity().getContentLength(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+response.getEntity().getContentLength(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "string creating :)",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get error at Bufferedreader in postExecute method...
LogCat o/p is as follows

```
E/ActivityThread(611): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf4cf0 that was originally bound here
```

Comment: Where is response declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

Use your code in the following manner if your response is in json and then use your 'response' from entity in `doInBackground(Void... params)`:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(serviceURL);                                   
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Reply with error what you result you get..